# Minimization over a function is equivalent to the problem of finding the minimum energy eigenstate in an infinite potential well?

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, variational-principle

I'm reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.05428v2) [Eqs.(10,11)] and met the following problem. The author states that the following minimization problem
$$
\underset{\tilde{g}\left( \mu \right)}{\min}\,\,\int_a^b{\left| \frac{\mathrm{d}\tilde{g}\left( \mu \right)}{\mathrm{d}\mu} \right|^2d\mu}, \tag{1}
$$
where the function is supported (nonzero domain) in the interval $[a,b]$ and is normalized in this interval. Namely, we have
$$
\int_a^b{\left| \tilde{g}\left( \mu \right) \right|^2d\mu}=1, \\ 
\tilde{g}\left( a \right) =\tilde{g}\left( b \right) =0. \tag 2
$$
My question is, how is this minimization problem equivalent to the problem of finding the minimum energy eigenstate in an infinite potential well with width $b-a$, hence has the minimum $\frac{\pi^2}{[b-a]^2}$? I try to deem $\tilde g(\mu)$ as a wave function and $\mu$ as its spatial position. However, I can't see what's the "Schrodinger equation" the function $\tilde g(\mu)$ needs to satisfy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Schrödinger equation" of your problem is the eigenvalue equation $$- \frac{d^2 \tilde{g}(\mu)}{d\mu^2} = \lambda \tilde{g}(\mu), \qquad \tilde{g}(a)=\tilde{g}(b)=0.$$ Obviously, the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ can be characterized by $$\lambda_1= \min\limits_{\tilde{g}, ||\tilde{g}||=1} \int\limits_a^b \! d \mu \, \tilde{g}^\ast \!(\mu)\left(-\frac{d^2 \tilde{g}(\mu)}{d\mu^2}    \right)=\min\limits_{\tilde{g}, ||\tilde{g}||=1}\int\limits_a^b\! d\mu \, \left|\frac{d \tilde{g}(\mu)}{d\mu} \right|^2, $$ where partial integration was used in the last step and $||\tilde{g}||$ is defined by $$||\tilde{g}||^2=\int\limits_a^b \! d\mu \,|\tilde{g}(\mu)|^2.  $$

Comment: Aha, your deduction is insightful, and thank you for your answer! But I hope I can make things more clear. The aim is to obtain the minimum of Eq.(1) with restrictions Eq.(2). But why the minimum is $\frac{\pi^2}{(b-a)^2}$? Besides Eq.(2), if we add the Schrödinger equation you mentioned in your answer, the minimization is then, as also stated in the original paper, equivalent to the problem of finding the minimum energy eigenstate in an infinite potential well. But what if another $\tilde g(\mu)$ does not satisfy your eigenvalue equation can have a smaller value?

Comment: Your "obviously" is actually non-trivial, but okay. It is the Ritz variation principle. See also Rayleigh-Ritz method or Rayleigh quotient.

Comment: @narip You can solve the eigenvalue equation and determine the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions explicitly (a simple home-work exercise) answering your remaing questions.

Comment: @Hyperon I mean, Eq.(2) does not have the eigenvalue equation restriction. For example, we can choose $\tilde g(\mu)\propto (\mu-a)(b-\mu)$ which satisfies Eq.(2) while does not satisfy your eigenvalue equation.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Sure! Well, even a novice in QM should have no problems to appreciate that fact the smallest eigenvalue of an observable must be $\le$ than the expectation value in an arbitrary state.

Comment: @narip Of course you can insert any normalized function satisfying $\tilde{g}(a)=\tilde{g}(b)=0$ and the expectation value of the "Hamilton" operator $-d^2/d\mu^2$ in this state will be $\ge$ $\lambda_1$. This is just what the theorem shown in my answer says. But the minimum value $\lambda_1$ is attained if you insert the (normalized) eigenfunction associated with $\lambda_1$. You find all this in any reasonable text-book on QM in the chapter on "variational methods".